# Fixed-size HTML table cells, even when content is too big?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a diagram using HTML. I used a table with fixed with columns. Everything looks well, but if the content of the a cell is too long, the column width is expanded. I would like the column width to remain fixed, even if some of the content is hidden.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: How to set the table column width constant regardless of the amount of text in its cells?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457506/css-how-to-set-the-table-column-width-constant-regardless-of-the-amount-of-text)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to @barrylloyd's answer, I'd suggest also using:

```
td,th {
  min-width: 3em; /* the normal 'fixed' width */
  width: 3em; /* the normal 'fixed' width */
  max-width: 3em; /* the normal 'fixed' width, to stop the cells expanding */
}
```

The `min-width` might be unnecessary, but it covers all the bases.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The combination of overflow: hidden and max-width: 1em did the trick!

Answer (score 7):

Try...

> table {table-layout: fixed}

in your stylesheet.

This forces the browser to use the fixed table layout algorithm...

> Fixed table layout algorithm:
>
> - The horizontal layout only depends on the table's width and the width of the columns, not the contents of the cells
> - Allows a browser to lay out the table faster than the automatic table layout
> - The browser can begin to display the table once the first row has been received

(See http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_tab_table-layout.asp)

Comment: The only thing I would add to this is that the text might still overflow the `td` (e.g., if you have a super-long string) and that if *that* happens then you want to consider wrapping the `td` contents in a `div` with `overflow:auto` set.

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 1):

How about CSS to address it:

```
td { overflow: hidden; }
```

Should probably be enough.

Comment: I don't believe that a `td` respects the `overflow` property.